# Can application create file in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Our web application is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk instance and from the code, I want to create a text/csv file.

do I need to have permission to create a file? or is it enabled by default?

How should I give permission to create a new file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its enabled by default.

In my Java application (running on EBS Tomcat) I use this system property to identify a temporary directory to write to:

```
// Get a temporary folder to write the attachment file in
final String dirPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

If I remember correctly this just gives me the path `/tmp`

Comment: Yes, it is `/tmp`